# Spring data elasticSearch page no totalpage

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

```
springBootVersion = '2.0.0.RC2'
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
```

Page findDistinctEsBlogByTitleContainingOrSummaryContainingOrContentContainingOrTagsContaining(String title, String summary, String content, String tags, Pageable pageable);
int totalPages = page.getTotalPages();
System.out.println(totalPages);
totalPages alwarys is 1

Comment: Could you also indicate how many total elements are returned, along with the page size defined in the Pageable please?

Comment: A bug is already open in Spring Data ElasticSearch's JIRA: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-413